# How to check if the puppeteer is finish downloading the file

Tags: puppeteer

I'm using this code to download files. I just hide the urls for security reasons. In the code below how can I check if the puppeteer has finished downloading the file

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
await page.goto('https://');
await page.waitForSelector('#aaa');
await page.goto('https://');
await page.waitForSelector('#bbb');
await page.goto('https://');
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see the Puppeteer documentation as this is a very basic first step when working with Puppeteer.

```
page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })
```

This will:
"consider navigation to be finished when there are no more than 0 network connections for at least 500 ms."

https://pptr.dev/

Comment: encountered Error: net::ERR_ABORTED but still it download the file

Comment: I don't think that error will be caused by that line. You may need to dig into that error a bit more to find the cause.

Comment: Also, ensure you are awaiting that waitForNavigation function.